# How to shorten VBA code using repeated SUMIFS function?

Tags: vba, function, concatenation, repeat, sumifs

I have written up a number of SUMIFS in VBA based on the change of a value in cells

E.g. Cell A23 is a drop down menu with Total and UK

```
If A23 = "Total" Then
Result.Range("A24").Value =     WorkSheetFunction.Sumifs(Range(B:B)),
Range(C:C)), "Year",
Range(D:D)), "Group")

If A23 = "UK" Then
Result.Range("A24").Value = WorkSheetFunction.Sumifs(Range(B:B)),
Range(C:C)), "Year",
Range(D:D)), "Group",
Range(E:E)), "UK")
```

Based on the example above, the second code is a repeat of the first code but with an additional range included to pick up "UK"

Instead of constantly rewriting it is there a way I can shortern the code so I can simply concatenate any additional range I want to include?

So ideally I could have something like:

```
Test = Result.Range("A24").Value = WorkSheetFunction.Sumifs(Range(B:B)),
Range(C:C)), "Year",
Range(D:D)), "Group"

If A23 = Total Then
A24 = Test)

If A23 = UK Then
A24 = Test &, Range(E:E), "UK")
```

Is this possible and if so how can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

Could you enter the actual function in the cells, rather than do the `worksheetfunction` calculation in the vba? (doing worksheetfunction calculations won't actually enter the formula in the cells, just return the output value)

Something like this maybe:

```
Dim strFormula as String
strFormula = "=SUMIFS(B:B, C:C, ""Year"", D:D, ""Group"")"
'Thats the basic formula

If Result.Range("A23").Value = "UK" Then
    strFormula = replace(strFormula, ")", "E:E, ""UK"")")
    'that replaces the end bracket with the extra condition
End If

Result.Range("A4").FormulaA1 = strFormula
```

Comment: If you did only want the output value at the end, not the formula left in, you could always add a line afterwards to fix that, something like ```Result.Range("A4").FormulaR1C1 = Result.Range("A4").Value``` maybe...

Comment: Thanks I'm getting a expected end of statement error when I try this when I try to break the line with _. The actual code I'm working with is WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(Range(rngHeaders.Find(LIC) , rngHeaders.Find(LIC).End(xlDown)), _ Range(rngHeaders.Find(Region), rngHeaders.Find(Region).End(xlDown)), Result.Range(A23), _ Range(rngHeaders.Find(Year), rngHeaders.Find(Year).End(xlDown)), "Year 0")

Comment: Not sure if this works when I'm trying to also do a For Next loop

Comment: the expected end of statement error - are you trying to put the line break in during a text string? If that's the case, you'd need to end the string (put in a double-quote " ), then put '&' and the line break (in either order) and then on the next line resume the string again. Effectively adds two separate parts of the string together.

Comment: Looking at your code though, it would also probably be better practice to `dim` a load of ranges rather than doing all those `.find` operations partway through the formula and confusing things ...

Answer (score 0):

(this answer posted mainly in response to that second comment with the actual code included - although it looks like the actual operation you're doing is a bit different?)

So, as I said you need to simplify that code out a bit by saving the separate parts in variables

```
Dim strFormula as String
Dim rngLIC as Range
Dim rngRegion as Range
Dim rngYear as Range

Set rngLIC = Range(rngHeaders.Find(LIC) , rngHeaders.Find(LIC).End(xlDown))
Set rngRegion = Range(rngHeaders.Find(Year), rngHeaders.Find(Year).End(xlDown))
Set rngYear = Range(rngHeaders.Find(Year), rngHeaders.Find(Year).End(xlDown))

'and I think you'll need to add others for the extra bit you wanted to fix, but you get the pattern

strFormula = "=SUMIFS(" & _
                rngLIC.Address(xlA1) & "," & _
                rngRegion.Address(xlA1) & ", A23," & _
                rngYear.Address(xlA1) & ", ""Year 0"")"

'Then add the replace bit I detailed above if necessary to add bits to the formula
```

That code should hopefully do xsactly the same as the code snippet you put in the comment. Does that help? (please vote up if it does because I'm trying to build my reputation!!)

Comment: Issue now is where I want to do a For Next loop. So For a = 0 To 7 Result.Cells(27 + a,  2).Value = WorksheetFunction.Sumifs(Range........

Comment: Sorry, that doesn't describe the issue very clearly? What goes wrong? If you want ranges to move down or whatever, then just add a line at the end of each loop to say e.g. `set rngLIC = rngLIC.Offset(a, 0)`